# How to insert multiple elements into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, block

I'm modeling a chessboard and was wondering if there is a populate a multidimensional array using #new.  I want each 'row' in the array to be initially populated with a `'*'` 
    ie. `[[ '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], [ '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'], etc... ]`

```
empty_frame = Array.new(8){[]}   #Can you use code block to fill here?
```

Or do i need to iterate through each 'row' to populate it?

Answer (score 3):

You did the first level correctly using a block. Why not do the same with the second level?

```
empty_frame = Array.new(8){Array.new(8){"*"}}
```

or

```
empty_frame = Array.new(8){Array.new(8, "*")}
```

If you are doing destructive operations on the string, then you probably need the first form.